# Double counting of char

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a code that count the inputs inputted one by one without counting blanks and . as MARK

```
#include "boolean.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#define MARK '.'

char currentChar;
boolean EOP;



void ADV(){
    if(currentChar == MARK){
        EOP = true;
    } else{
        scanf("%c",&currentChar);
    }
}

void START(){
    scanf("%c",&currentChar);
    if(currentChar == MARK){
        EOP = true;
    } 
}

char GetCC(){
    return currentChar;
}
boolean IsEOP(){
    return (currentChar==MARK);
}


int hitungkarakter(char karakter)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(karakter != " " && karakter != MARK){
        i++ ;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(){
    START();
    int i = 0;
    while(!IsEOP()){
        i+=hitungkarakter(currentChar);
        ADV();
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

However, the algorithm i+=hitungkarakter adds twice everytime. How do I fix this?

It works fine if I add . directly but other inputs prints out twice.
One such example:

```
f
1
m
2
3
k
4
5
.
6
```